# Is it possible to detect Windows dark mode on winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a winforms application using all those flat style options, and it makes the application look a lot like Win10 applications, so I was wondering if is it possible to detect if the OS is using dark mode, so I could adjust the colors to fit the dark (or light) mode.

I found some questions about it, but they were related to UWP and WPF, so the solutions didn't work on my apllication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the current user preferences from the Windows Registry:

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize`

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Took me a while to find out how to access the value via code, but it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Based on Waescher's solution, here is the code for that:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

try
{
    int res = (int)Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize", "AppsUseLightTheme", -1);
}
catch 
{
 //Exception Handling     
}
```

res contains the value for the default theme on windows

0 : dark theme

1 : light theme

-1 : AppsUseLightTheme could not be found

Comment: If you're using Dark Mode for System, but not apps, then this will always return 1 (Light).  So I used the key `SystemUsesLightTheme` instead of `AppsUseLightTheme`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answers, here is my approach:

```
/// <summary>Returns Windows Color Mode for Applications.
/// <para>0=dark theme, 1=light theme</para>
/// </summary>
public static int GetWindowsColorMode(bool GetSystemColorModeInstead = false)
{
    try
    {
        return (int)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(
            @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize",
            GetSystemColorModeInstead ? "SystemUsesLightTheme" : "AppsUseLightTheme", 
            -1);
    }
    catch
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```